# Activiti stack traces are huge. How to reduce?

Tags: performance, logging, activiti

In our application, we're using Activiti and the issue is that in the log we're getting very large exception stack traces, a couple of hundreds of rows per exception.
Also, the huge stack trace doesn't give additional useful information, so there is no good reason for us to have it.

I'm sure everyone who uses Activiti encountered this issue. How can we reduce the stack traces' size?

Answer (score 2):

Activiti uses slf4j, so one option is to use the logback binding and customize its output using the %ex layout option.

You can find more information in the following link:

[Chapter 6: Layouts](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#ex)

The relevant options are copied below:

- ex{depth}
- exception{depth}
- throwable{depth}
- ex{depth, evaluator-1, ..., evaluator-n}
- exception{depth, evaluator-1, ..., evaluator-n}
- throwable{depth, evaluator-1, ..., evaluator-n}

Outputs the stack trace of the exception associated with the logging event, if any. By default the full stack trace will be output.

The throwable conversion word can followed by one of the following options:

- short: prints the first line of the stack trace
- full: prints the full stack trace
- Any integer: prints the given number of lines of the stack trace

*Examples*

```
Conversion Pattern     Result
%ex                    mainPackage.foo.bar.TestException: Houston we have a problem
                        at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire(TestThrower.java:22)
                        at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.readyToLaunch(TestThrower.java:17)
                        at mainPackage.ExceptionLauncher.main(ExceptionLauncher.java:38)

%ex{short}             mainPackage.foo.bar.TestException: Houston we have a problem
                        at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire(TestThrower.java:22)

%ex{full}              mainPackage.foo.bar.TestException: Houston we have a problem
                        at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire(TestThrower.java:22)
                        at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.readyToLaunch(TestThrower.java:17)
                        at mainPackage.ExceptionLauncher.main(ExceptionLauncher.java:38)

%ex{2}                 mainPackage.foo.bar.TestException: Houston we have a problem
                        at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.fire(TestThrower.java:22)
                        at mainPackage.foo.bar.TestThrower.readyToLaunch(TestThrower.java:17)
```